# 画像処理後の画像の左と下にあるピクセル軸（画素軸）を非表示若しくは取り除きたい

Tags: python, opencv, 画像, google-colaboratory, 画像処理

**前提・実現したいこと**
Python初心者です。今回はGoogle Colabにて標題の様な事を実現したいと思っています。具体的には参考URLに存在する画像（図1）をサイズ変更（512×512に変更）して保存した結果、画像の左側と下側に縦横軸それぞれ512迄表記された状態となる為、これを非表示にするか取り除いてボールだけの画像にしたいと考えています。
参考URL：https://data-analysis-stats.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/OpenCV_color.html
[image: 図1]
図1

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
素人質問で恐縮ですがこれを実行出来るプログラムが分かりません。私の方で調査した結果、これを非表示にする方法はありませんでした。これを受け、自力で画像を抽出して無理矢理除外するプログラムを作成しましたが、綺麗にリサイズできる訳でもなく、しかも大量にある画像を一々画像のサイズが違うものを数字で入力していく訳にもいきません。エラーメッセージは出ませんでした。図2がピクセル軸が入ってしまった画像です。
[image: 図2]
図2

**該当のソースコード**
上記で記載した私の自作プログラムを記します。しかしこの方法では綺麗にピクセル軸を取り除く事は出来ない上、サイズの違う画像があればその都度数字を変更しなくてはなりません。私が作成できるプログラムはここまでです。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

#画像を読み込む

img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/ball.png")
print(img.shape)
#画像の一部を切り取る
im2 = img[0:230,30:250]

cv2.imwrite('./content/drive/MyDrive/new_ball.png', im2)

#画像を表示
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

出力は次の図3の様になります。上手くいっていませんね。
[image: 図3]
図3

**試したこと**
先述の様に出来るだけの調査をして、実用性の低いプログラムを作りましたが上手くいっていない状態です。このピクセル軸を非表示若しくは除外するプログラムをご教授お願い致します。

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**
言語：Python
環境：Windows10
ブラウザ：Google　chrome（Google　Colaboratory)
＊ノートパソコンです。全て最新バージョンです。プログラミング中はcolab以外のタブ、アプリは開いていません。

Comment: plt.axis("off")

Comment: 前回に引き続き回答ありがとうございます。大変ビックリする程簡単な答えでした。無事解決した事をご報告させていただきます。